# attachments with tags and get_posts

Tags: attachments, tags, get-posts

having problems with filtering a posts attachments by tag... It worked fine until i added the tag__in arg (and other variations of it).

```
$vidArgs = array(
                            'tag__in' =>5,
                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                            'post_mime_type'=>'video/quicktime',
                            'posts_per_page'=>20
                        );

$videos = get_posts($vidArgs);

foreach ($videos as $vid) { ///....
```

pointers / advice appreciated!

**UPDATES**
it is odd. It just doesn't work with media tags! Added *testtag* to a post and it comes up.
There must be a way to get attachments by tags? Otherwise what's the point? The functionality is in wp admin from the Media Tags pane...

```
$argsc = array(
    /* 'tag' => 'commercials,testtag',  */
    'tag__in' => array(5,11),
    'post_type'=>array('post','page','attachment'),
    'post_status'=>'any',
    /* 'post_parent'=>$post->ID, */
    'posts_per_page'=>20
);

$the_queryB = get_posts( $argsc);

echo count($the_queryB).", <pre>";
print_r($the_queryB);
```

Comment: WordPress tags aren't associated with attachments natively, i don't think(assume) the `WP_Query` class supports querying attachments by taxonomy(because it's not a natively supported feature, despite the fact it can be enabled). Try the same query minus the mime and using the `post` post type, if results come back fine then it confirms what i've said.

Comment: Also note, `get_posts` defaults to `publish` `post_status`, if you're querying attachments you need to explicitly set the `post_status` parameter.

Comment: thanks t3 - figured out the post_status yesterday which helped but the tags element still doesn't work. Can this function really not exist?!

Comment: My point is i don't think `WP_Query` was written with any expectation for attachments to have taxonomies, and therefore may not work as a result(i could be wrong of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found n easy way of doing this now! Getting images by 'your case' tag and logged in user.

```
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'attachment', 
'author' => $current_user->ID,
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'media_tag',
                'terms' => 'yourcase',
                'field' => 'slug',
            )
        )
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
```

UPDATE. media_tag seems to be a custom taxonomy added by the file gallery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) in the codex, i see that this parameter requires an array so i'd try this way:

```
$vidArgs = array(
                            'tag__in' => array(5),
                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                            'post_mime_type'=>'video/quicktime',
                            'posts_per_page'=>20
                        );

$videos = get_posts($vidArgs);

foreach ($videos as $vid) { ///....
```

Comment: thanks kevin but tried that earlier & doesn't work...

Comment: What if you use the **tag_id** instead?

Comment: afraid not! Seems odd as thought this would be fairly straight forward..;-/

Comment: have you tryed all others parameters? Stupid question, are you sure there is a tag with the id you require and a post that matches those arguments?

Comment: yeh - really annoying. maybe something to do with attachments?

Comment: and if you get rid of this **post_mime_type**?

Comment: @danielCrabbe let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/992/discussion-between-kevin-and-daniel-crabbe)